# Putting chapter headings of appendices in the middle of the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning

Is there a way to put the chapter headings of appendices in the middle of the page, then start the content of the chapter (in my case the content is a table which is too big for a page, so it automatically start in the next page). For example the below is my code (it is one of the \input{} of my main code)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents} \tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} \listoftables
\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \listoffigures
\doublespacing
\begin{appendices}
\chapter{First chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixA: 1st Chapter heading}
\input{First chapter table which overflow the page.tex}
\chapter{Second chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixB: 2nd Chapter heading}
\input{Something_else.tex}
\chapter{Third chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixC: 3rd Chapter heading}
\input{Something_else.tex}
\chapter{Fourth chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixD: 4th Chapter heading}
\input{Something_else.tex}
\chapter{Fifth chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixE: 5th Chapter heading}
\input{Something_else.tex}
\end{appendices} 
\end{document}
```

From the code above, is it possible to put the "First chapter heading", "Second chapter heading", etc in the middle of the page and at the same time can be displayed in the Table of Contents?

Please advise me, thank you very much in advance!

Tommy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `titlesec` package and make the new definitions of chapter inside the appendices environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents} \tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables} \listoftables
\cleardoublepage\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} \listoffigures


\begin{appendices}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\chapter{First chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixA: 1st Chapter heading}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Second chapter heading}\label{appendix: AppendixB: 2nd Chapter heading}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{appendices}

\chapter{test normal chapter}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi koleygr, thank you so much for your help!!! It works perfectly as the way I wanted. Thank you!!! If you don't mind one more question, is it possible to put more white space on the top of the heading, so that the heading can be positioned in the middle of the page (vertical wise).

Comment: There is a `20pt` before `{\Huge}` in the titleformat command. Replace it with: `0.2\paperheight` and tell me if this is what you want. If it is ok, consider accepting the answer as correct...